# css style for display inline

Tags: html, css

I want to display a `<h1>` tag and `button` tag in same line, but the `button` appear slightly below. I marked In green where I want to display it:

[image]

```css
h1{
    display:inline-block; 
}

.log {
    width:60%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
    background-color: #e5e3e3;
    border: 0px solid #f9f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:20px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="log">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <form method="post"> 
        <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
    </form>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just modified this:

```
form {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.log {
  width: 60%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 0px solid #f9f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
form {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="log">
  <h1>Profile</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <button class="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
  </form>

</div>
<!--End of log div -->
```

or you can do it with:

```
form{
    display:inline; 
}
```

Comment: can you say what you modified please

Comment: this doesn't work in my code.If I add inline style to form its working but I dont want to add inline style.

Comment: could you please show the output you get when you add this code to your form

Comment: ya sure.I will add screen shot

Comment: where is the screen shot you upload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72449/discussion-between-user3386779-and-priya786).

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline for the `<h1>` tag, and now you can put the inline in your `form` tag as below:

```
<form method="post" style="display:inline"> 
     <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Its working in inline css style.but I have all my css in another page sir.Is any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1{
    display:inline-block; 
}

.log {
    width:60%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
    background-color: #e5e3e3;
    border: 0px solid #f9f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:20px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
form{
display:inline-block;
float:right;
  margin-top:20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="log">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <form method="post"> 
        <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
    </form>      
</div>
```